# Как или где открыть .tpl файл?

Tags: javascript, php, html

коллеги. Столкнулся с такой задачей: есть сайт, который нужно запустить на локальном сервере (openserver). В расширении html файлов указано .tpl (index.tpl и т.п). Как открыть их в браузере если html файла для их сборки нет?

Comment: Любыой программой которая может открыть текстовый файл

Comment: не все сайты состоят из одних лишь html (возможно в браузере Вы и видите что это html, но внутри это моржет быть что угодно). Предполагаю что это и не html, а динамический шаблон, который обрабатывается каким-то скриптом. Смотрите может это у Вас CMS или фреймворк какой-то

Answer (score 0):

.tpl файлы используются в качестве шаблонов страниц в PHP движках. Такие сайты запускаются в браузере через систему управления каркаса php? Лайк!)